# What is the minimum distance from property line water can be drained?

Tags: drainage, sump-pump, downspout

My city (Redmond, WA) enforces the 2015 International Residential Code, but I could not find any requirements around distances of downspout and/or sump pump drainage from property lines. Perhaps I'm not searching on the right nomenclature.

What is the minimum distance from property line water can be drained? Does it differ for downspouts and sump pumps?

Please refrain from sharing recommended distances. I'm looking for the code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about local code are off-topic

Comment: @Machavity - when did that happen? Not that it matters, "My city" isn't a location.

Comment: It’s a legal issue. You can’t do anything on your property to affect someone else’s property.

Comment: This question was and is targeted towards the 2015 International Residential Code and not  "my city". However, since you've asked for the city, I've added it.

Answer (score 1):

None that I know of in 'The Code', your Zoning is what determines specific buffers. However, the Rule Of Thumb around me says you can't discharge any water in the direction of your neighbor that would readily flow over the property line...no downspout extension legs directed at your neighbor.

In the few States I've worked it's all the same and I wouldn't doubt you're in the same boat. This includes no flow allowed over pavements and sidewalks and no curb nor sewer outlets. All water must be given the chance to absorb into your property.

Check with your Codes, Zoning, Buildings, Permits or Inspection Department (whatever yours is called).

Comment: Google 'zoning laws' for the location known as "My city". +1